# displaying a variable in a popup window with kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make a program that reads the dictionary after the user inputs their name and assigns a random selection based on weighted values in the dictionary. As of now the logic for selecting a random value from the dictionary is working but I have it printing to the console. I would like it to appear in a popup window (which i have but cannot get the output variable to show up there)

four.kv

```py
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name:'main'
    player_python:player_kv

    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        GridLayout:
            cols:2

            Label:
                text:'Player:'

            TextInput:
                id: player_kv
                multiline: False

        Button:
            text: 'Random'
            on_press: root.btn()


<P>:
    output:output

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            id: output
```

main4.py

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

import random
#from Dict import *
#### example dictionary
character = {
'John':
            {'Water': 2,            #50%
             'Fire': 1,              #25%
             'Earth': 1,},           #25%
'Bill':
            {'Water': 1,         #25%
             'Fire': 2,             #50%
             'Earth': 1,}}         #25%
####
class MainWindow(Screen):
    player_python = ObjectProperty(None)
    output = StringProperty('')

    def btn(self):
        show_popup()
        player = self.player_python.text
        weighted_list = []


        for c in character[player]:
            for w in range(character[player][c]):
                weighted_list.append(c)
        self.output= random.choice(weighted_list)

        print(self.output)            ###### instead of this printing to console I want it to display in popup window

        self.player_python.text = ''

class P(FloatLayout):
    pass



def show_popup():
    show = P()
    popupWindow = Popup(title='random character', content=show, size_hint=(None,None),size=(400,400) )
    popupWindow.open()


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file('four.kv')


class FourApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FourApp().run()
```

https://gist.github.com/PatrickToole/00cc72cdd7ff5146976e5d92baad8e02

Thanks in advance

-P

Comment: Hi ptoole, please post a [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this code, but try passing `self.output` to your `show_popup()` method. This would mean changing your `btn()` method to something like:

```
def btn(self):
    player = self.player_python.text
    weighted_list = []


    for c in character[player]:
        for w in range(character[player][c]):
            weighted_list.append(c)
    self.output= random.choice(weighted_list)

    print(self.output)            ###### instead of this printing to console I want it to display in popup window

    self.player_python.text = ''
    show_popup(self.output)
```

And in the `show_popup()` method:

```
def show_popup(output):
    show = P()
    show.output.text = output
    popupWindow = Popup(title='random character', content=show, size_hint=(None,None),size=(400,400) )
    popupWindow.open()
```

As I mentioned, I haven't tested this code, but something like this should work.